# How to keep track of trending hashtag from Twitter and display on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, npm-package

I would like to make API call every 5 minutes and display latest trending hashtag under 5 minutes card. Likewise, I would like to have 10minutes ago, 15minutes ago, 20 minutes ago trend card which  displays what was trending 10minutes ago,15minutes ago,and 20minutes ago. Similar to what this site is displaying https://trends24.in/united-states/. My Current issue is trends are getting updatedevery 5 minutes under 5 minutes ago trend card, but I am not sure how to populate the hashtags  along with tweet counts under 10minutes ago,15minutes ago and 20 minutes ago ? Below is my code.

I am new to Web development so any help on this is much appreciated!

**JS Code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const Twit = require('twit');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve static files from the current directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Twitter API credentials
const apikey = '';
const apisecretkey = '';
const accesstoken = '';
const accesstokensecret = '';

const T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: apikey,
  consumer_secret: apisecretkey,
  access_token: accesstoken,
  access_token_secret: accesstokensecret,
  timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'chatgpt.html'));
});

function fetchTrendingHashtags(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    T.get('trends/place', params)
      .then((result) => {
        const trends = result.data[0].trends;

        // Filter out hashtags with null tweet counts
        const validTrends = trends.filter((trend) => trend.tweet_volume !== null);

        // Take the top 10 trending hashtags
        const topTrends = validTrends.slice(0, 10);

        const simplifiedTrends = topTrends.map((trend) => {
          return {
            hashtag: trend.name,
            tweetCount: trend.tweet_volume,
          };
        });

        resolve(simplifiedTrends);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching trends:', error);
        reject('Error fetching trends');
      });
  });
}

app.get('/trends', (req, res) => {
  const params = { id: '23424977' };

  fetchTrendingHashtags(params)
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});

const timeIntervals = [
  { minutes: 5, containerId: 'hashtags-container' }

];

timeIntervals.forEach((interval) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const newParams = { id: '23424977' }; 
    fetchTrendingHashtags(newParams)
      .then((data) => {
        // Update the hashtags container with new data without sorting
        updateHashtagsContainer(interval.containerId, data);
        console.log(`Fetched trends for ${interval.minutes || interval.hours} ago`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error fetching trends for ${interval.minutes || interval.hours} ago:`, error);
      });
  }, (interval.minutes || interval.hours) * 60 * 1000); // Convert minutes/hours to milliseconds
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" class="src">

  <title>Trending Hashtags</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .trending-card {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .twitter-trends {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      display: flex; /* Make the logo and text display inline */
      align-items: center; /* Center vertically within the line */
    }

    .trend-item {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 2px 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a bottom border for each trend */
    }

    .trend-item span:first-child {
      margin-right: 10px;
      width: 25px; /* Adjust the width to your preference */
      text-align: right;
    }

    .trend-item span:last-child {
      flex: 1; /* Allow the text to fill the remaining space */
      text-align: right; /* Align tweet volume counts to the right */
    }

    .trend-item span:last-child span {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent line breaks */
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Add ellipsis (...) for long hashtags */
    }

     /* Remove the border-bottom from the last trend */
     .trend-item:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="trending-card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-4">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter fa-2xl"></i>
        <span class="twitter-trends">Trends</span>
      </div>
      <div class="timestamp-container">
        <span class="timestamp">5 minutes ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group" id="hashtags-container">
        <!-- Trending hashtags will be displayed here -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trending cards with different time intervals -->
    <div class="trending-card">
      <div class="timestamp-container">
        <span class="timestamp">10 minutes ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group" id="hashtags-container-10">
        <!-- Trending hashtags will be displayed here -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="trending-card">
      <div class="timestamp-container">
        <span class="timestamp">15 minutes ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group" id="hashtags-container-15">
        <!-- Trending hashtags will be displayed here -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="trending-card">
      <div class="timestamp-container">
        <span class="timestamp">20 minutes ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group" id="hashtags-container-20">
        <!-- Trending hashtags will be displayed here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    function fetchAndUpdateHashtags(containerId, timeAgo) {
      fetch(`/trends?time=${timeAgo}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(`Error fetching trends for ${timeAgo} ago:`, error));
    }

  
    // Define the function to update hashtags container
    function updateHashtagsContainer(containerId, data) {
      const hashtagsContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
      hashtagsContainer.innerHTML = '';

      data.forEach((item, index) => {
        const trendItem = document.createElement('div');
        trendItem.className = 'trend-item';
        trendItem.innerHTML = `
          <span>${index + 1}.</span>
          <span><span>${item.hashtag}</span></span>
          <span class="text-secondary">${formatTweetVolume(item.tweetCount)}</span>
        `;
        hashtagsContainer.appendChild(trendItem);
      });
    }

    function formatTweetVolume(volume) {
      if (volume >= 1000) {
        return (volume / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k';
      }
      return volume;
    }

    // Fetch trending hashtags for different time intervals initially
    fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container', '5min'); // 5 minutes ago
 

    setInterval(() => {
      fetchAndUpdateHashtags('hashtags-container', '5min');
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000); // 5 minutes interval
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, nothing to do with Java.